# Accessibility reading showing items in a listview as list item + header view

Tags: android, listview, accessibility

I am implementing accessibility in my custom pull to refresh list view. My pull to refresh list view has a header view to show the updating status while pull down. If my list contains only 5 items, Talkback reads it as "showing item 1 of 6" instead of "showing item 1 of 5". I think it took total count as list items + header views (ie, 5 items + 1 header view).

I want to remove the header view count from this.

I have tried `headerView.setImportantForAccessibility(IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS);` but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Every adapter item (including headers) is represented in the count. Changing the reported count would cause the actual ListView contents to be inconsistent with the data reported to accessibility services and is not recommended.

Comment: Is there any way that we can change reading list count in ListView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
mListView.setAccessibilityDelegate(new View.AccessibilityDelegate(){
        @Override
        public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host, AccessibilityNodeInfo info) {
            super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);
            AccessibilityNodeInfo.CollectionInfo old = info.getCollectionInfo();
            info.setCollectionInfo(AccessibilityNodeInfo.CollectionInfo.obtain(
                    old.getRowCount() - mListView.getHeaderViewsCount() - mListView.getFooterViewsCount(),
                    old.getColumnCount(),
                    old.isHierarchical(),
                    old.getSelectionMode()));
        }
    });
```