# Screen reader announces incorrect number of items in Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, screen-readers, navigationview

I'm having a navigation view which contains a header and a menu. This menu is having 19 clickable items, 3 group headers and 4 dividers.

Somehow, when I open the drawer and focus on some item, the screen reader says that there are 20 items in list. I assume this is about those 19 clickable items + 1 navigation header.

Still the strangest thing is that when I scroll down or up it's saying "Showing items x to y of 27" and never goes back to 20 again (unless I reopen the drawer). I assume is about those 19 clickable items + 3 group headers + 4 dividers + 1 navigation header = 27.

How can I change this? I expect that the navigation header to not be included on this count, dividers neither.

I've tried the suggestion here [Accessibility reading showing items in a listview as list item + header view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35079056/accessibility-reading-showing-items-in-a-listview-as-list-item-header-view/49324178) in order to get rid of the navigation header count, but it does not work because when it comes to a navigation view, getCollectionInfo returns null.

I have also tried to override onDrawerOpened/Close/StateChanged/Slide methods in order to prevent the screen reader to announce any number at all with no success.

I've seen that the Talk Back behaved the same until a workaround has been added https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/678 but as I could see, nothing happened for screen reader.

Does anyone know how to stop the screen reader to announce this incorrect number?

Comment: Did you find a way to override what the voiceover says?